# How to do scroll on iOS native app with webdriver.io?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, webdriver-io

I am trying to scroll on iOS native app using webdriver.io framework.
I am using this API:
browser.touchAction({
  action: 'moveTo', x: 1, y: 2
});

getting error: not yet implemented. Is there any other ways to scroll?

Comment: Can u check the java client version u r using.May be the function is deprecated

Comment: @sai Its not java, its JS

Answer (score 1):

Use this command to scroll:

```
client.execute("mobile: scroll", {direction: 'down'})
```

Answer (score 1):

browser.execute ('mobile:scroll', {direction:down});

Reference:
https://appium.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/commands/mobile-command

Or one more workaround command is there which scrolls to the specified selector.

browser.getLocation (selector);

Selector can be xpath /css selector

Comment: the problem I have with this current implementation is that it does two scrolls

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using wrong api point. According to api documentations on webdriver.io website, you should use 
browser.touchScroll(id,xoffset,yoffset);

you can check it here http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/touchScroll.html#description

Comment: touchScroll does not work well, need to use touchAction to scroll. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

browser.touchAction([{action: 'press', x: 10, y: firstY}, { action: 'moveTo', x: 10, y: secondY }, 'release'])

Comment: My press ends up clicking a button rather than doing the moveTo action. Did you ever have to get past that? @mike_dz

Answer (score 0):

```
browser.touchAction([
  { action: 'press', x: 1000, y: 1000 },
  { action: 'moveTo', x: 1000, y: -10000 },
  'release'
]);
```

use y = -ve value for scrolling down.

Answer (score -1):

wanna let you know that in built scroll method is deprecated from appium version 1.3+

```
Now you can use swipe method
browser.swipe([selector][,xoffset][,yoffset][,speed]);
```

selector is element

xoffset - relative x cordinate

yoffset- relative y coordinate

speed - in ms the operation should be performed